# PubSub Maximum delivery attempts & Dead letter topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Happy May 1st,

I'm doing a simple POC to utilize the dead letter topic feature of PusSub. I configured my subscription to republish messages to a separate dead letter topic after 20 Maximum delivery attempts (below is the subscription pull code and sample message used).
[image: Dead letter topic configuration]
Note: I configured the subscription using Cloud Console.

**Problem/challenge:** Even after 36 delivery attempts the test message is still not republished to the dead letter topic.  Based on the documentation I would assume my test message will be republished to the dead letter topic and shouldn't be delivered after 20 attempts.  What am I missing?
[image: 36 attempts even after I nack everytime]

**Pull Subscription code**

```js
const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub');
var moment = require('moment');  

process.env['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'abcxyz.json';

const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
const timeout = 100;

async function listenWithCustomAttributes() {
  const subscription = pubSubClient.subscription("projects/random-1234/subscriptions/testsub");
  
  // Create an event handler to handle messages
  const messageHandler = (message) => {

    const datetime = moment().format('mmmm do yyyy, h:mm:ss a');
    console.log(`${datetime}::: ${message.id}:`);
    console.log(`${message.data}`);
    console.log(`Delivery Attempt: ${message.deliveryAttempt}`);
    console.log(`custom Attributes: ${JSON.stringify(message.attributes)}`);
    console.log('\n');

    //NACK for re-delivery
    message.nack();
  };

  subscription.on('message', messageHandler);
  setTimeout(() => {
    subscription.removeListener('message', messageHandler);
  }, timeout * 1000000);
}

listenWithCustomAttributes();
```

**Sample PubSub message**

```js
const message   = {
    "event": "First",
    "message": "HELLOWORLD!!!!",
};
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to address this issue.

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#granting_forwarding_permissions)  "If you configured the subscription using Cloud Console, the roles are granted automatically." But, that no longer seems valid. We need to grant the required publisher & subscriber role in "DEAD LETTERING" (beside OVERVIEW) in the console of the subscription or add iam policy as described in the docs.
[image]